# A value of type Result<Vec<Type>, Error> cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type Vec<Type>

Tags: rust

I'm trying to work on a piece of code and am getting an error like this:

```
error[E0277]: a value of type `Result<Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>, AuthorizedClientConfigError>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>`
   --> crates/tor-hsservice/src/svc/publish/descriptor.rs:194:10
    |
194 |         .collect();
    |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Result<Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>, AuthorizedClientConfigError>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>>`
    |
    = help: the trait `FromIterator<Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>>` is not implemented for `Result<Vec<tor_llcrypto::pk::curve25519::PublicKey>, AuthorizedClientConfigError>`
    = help: the trait `FromIterator<Result<A, E>>` is implemented for `Result<V, E>`
note: the method call chain might not have had the expected associated types
```

My code looks like this:

```
let auth_client_keys: Result<Vec<curve25519::PublicKey>, Error> = auth_clients
    .authorized_client
    .iter()
    .flat_map(|client| match client {
        Curve25519Key(key) => Ok(vec![**key]),
        DirectoryOfKeys(dir) => {
            let mut keys = Vec::<curve25519::PublicKey>::new();

            Ok(keys)
        }
    })
    .collect()
```

I don't know how I can return to a type like `Result<Vec<curve25519::PublicKey>, AuthorizedClientConfigError>` if I am iterating through a loop with `iter()` and `flat_map()`. How do I do this and fix the above errors?

Am I better off with for loops, as that's usually easier?

I expected it to consolidate the maps the PublicKey class into a single for loop. Instead, I got the errors above.

Comment: The error message shows a `collect` call that your snippet does not feature. Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the error you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have the `Result` and `Vec` mixed up in the `flat_map` call, so it flattens the `Result` instead of the `Vec`
I.e. with the flat map the types of the item go from `Result<Vec<T>, E>` to `Vec<T>`, I think you wanted it to go to `Result<T, E>`.

To fix it you can just swap the vector and result creation in the call:

```rust
.flat_map(|client| match client {
    Curve25519Key(key) => vec![Ok(**key)],
    DirectoryOfKeys(dir) => {
        let mut keys = Vec::<curve25519::PublicKey>::new();
        let key_from_dir = read_key_from_dir();
        keys.push(Ok(key_from_dir));
        keys
    }
})
```